# maven-war-plugin does not change .war default directory

Tags: java, maven-plugin, maven-war-plugin

I try to change default .war directory by using maven-war-plugin

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</warSourceDirectory>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But it does not work. In the sense of my .war creates in the defaul (target) directory.
    I tried to use , but with the same result.
    What am I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`warSourceDirectory`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#warSourceDirectory) to configure additional directories to be packaged into the WAR file.

---

The **[`outputDirectory` property](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#outputDirectory)** should do what you want to achieve:

> The directory for the generated WAR.